# Meaning of dispersion relation for quantized EM field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Quantization_of_EM_field) on quantizing the electromagnetic field gives the following Hamiltonian and 3-momentum operators:
\begin{align} H&=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mu} \hbar \omega N^{(\mu)}(\mathbf{k})\\
\mathbf{P}&=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mu} \hbar \mathbf{k} N^{(\mu)}(\mathbf{k}),
\end{align}
where $N^{(\mu)}(\mathbf{k})$ is the number operator for wavevector $\mathbf{k}$ and polarization $\mu$, and $\omega=c|\mathbf{k}|$.

I had previously thought that the 4-momentum of a massless field satisfied $P^\mu P_\mu =0$, which would imply that $H^2=|\mathbf{P}|^2$. However, with the above definitions this is not the case due to the presence of cross-terms. To make this concrete, I will provide a state $| \Psi \rangle$ with $H^2 | \Psi \rangle\neq|\mathbf{P}|^2 | \Psi \rangle$:

Let $| \Psi \rangle$ be the state where the modes $\mu=1,\mathbf{k}=(1,0,0)$ and $\mu=1,\mathbf{k}=(-1,0,0)$ both contain one particle, and all other modes are unexcited. In words, we have a photon with leftward momentum $\hbar$ and a photon with rightward momentum $\hbar$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}| \Psi \rangle &= \left(\hbar(1,0,0)N^{(1)}((1,0,0))+\hbar (-1,0,0)N^{(1)}((-1,0,0))\right)| \Psi \rangle\\
&= \hbar (1,0,0)| \Psi \rangle+\hbar (-1,0,0)| \Psi \rangle\\
&=\mathbf{0}.
\end{align}

So $| \Psi \rangle$ has definite zero momentum. However the total energy is nonzero, since both particles have energy $\hbar c$:
\begin{align}
H| \Psi \rangle &= \left(\hbar c|(1,0,0)|N^{(1)}((1,0,0))+\hbar c|(-1,0,0)|N^{(1)}((-1,0,0))\right)| \Psi \rangle\\
&= \hbar c| \Psi \rangle+\hbar c| \Psi \rangle\\
&=2\hbar c | \Psi \rangle.
\end{align}

Therefore $H^2 | \Psi \rangle\neq|\mathbf{P}|^2 | \Psi \rangle$ in this example.

Why is it okay that $P^\mu P_\mu\neq 0$? Does this not contradict the fact that the EM field is massless?

Comment: Even classically, the relation $E^2-p^2=0$ applies only to an individual massless particle, not to a pair of massless particles having equal and opposite momenta.

Comment: So it is not true that $P^\mu P_\mu=0$ for a massless field? What is true instead?

Comment: Right. Almost all configurations of the classical EM field have $P^\mu P_\mu\neq 0$. Saying that a field is massless means that the energy of a sinusoidal plane-wave goes to zero as its momentum goes to zero. (In the quantum case, the corresponding particle is massless.) A static configuration of the field has non-zero energy but zero momentum, as does a pair of plane waves with opposite momenta of equal magnitude (zero total momentum, still non-zero total energy). Theoretically, in general relativity, we could make a black hole by concentrating enough EM radiation into one region of space.

Comment: Ok. I'd thought that $P^\mu P_\mu=m^2$, but [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_classification) actually says that $P^\mu P_\mu$ is "associated with mass-squared". I wish the wiki were a little clearer: what does it mean by "associated with"?

Comment: Not sure what the author meant by "associated with," but your are right: $P^\mu P_\mu$ is typically used as the *definition* of mass-squared. So almost all configurations of the classical EM field have "mass," even though individual photons (or single-wavenumber plane waves) are massless. Even for particles that individually have mass $m>0$, the total mass of a system of two particles with non-zero opposite momenta has mass $>2m$, because the energy in the zero-momentum frame is $>2mc^2$ (including the kinetic energy). Photons, with $m=0$, are no exception.

Comment: Ok - thanks for clearing that up!